# How do i return a single index of an array, by passing said array to a function in c#?

Tags: arrays

Im really confused in how to returning an array that is input in the main , and then passed to the DominantIndex() function, and then return back an int or a single index of the array input

```
    public static void Main()
    {

        int[] index = { 1,2,6,7,5,3,1 };
        DominantIndex(index);
    }

    public static int DominantIndex(int[] nums)
    {
        int maxindex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] > nums[maxindex])
            {
                maxindex = i;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
        {
            if (maxindex != j  && nums[maxindex] < 2 * nums[j])
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return maxindex;
    }
```

So what the function does is, it returns the index, of an element in the array, that is at least twice as largest to the other elements, if there isn't any, then the function returns -1

in this case, it returns -1

Comment: `int result = DominantIndex(index); Console.Write(result);`?

Comment: wouldn't it print out the whole array with that?

Comment: to print the entire array, you can `Join` its items: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", index));`

Comment: No, im not trying to print the entire array, only the specific index of it, that was found and or calculated in the function
but my problem is, i just cant find a way to return that index, by passing the array parameter in the Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be quite direct:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Having an array
    int[] index = { 1,2,6,7,5,3,1 };

    // We compute a dominant index 
    int result = DominantIndex(index);

    // And output the results (we have 2 cases):
    if (result >= 0) // dominant index exists
      Console.WriteLine($"Dominant index: {result}; Dominant value: {index[result]}");
    else             // array doesn't dominant index
      Console.WriteLine("No dominant index has been found.");
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you sir!
i didnt know, i thought it would print out the whole index, but it doesnt because i forgot it returns only maxindex